# Patient vs. subject in clinical research

Tags: differences, medical

What is the difference between patients and subjects, in clinical research?

I read [this paper abstract](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780471462422.eoct450/abstract):

> The terms “patient” and “subject” are often used interchangeably when proposing, conducting, or reporting on research. This error is not just a semantic one but also a conceptual one. Proper use of these terms is essential for all parties involved in the research to understand clearly their roles, expectations, and obligations.

which tends to make me think there might be some differences but the actual article is behind a paywall.

Comment: I would think that a "patient" is someone who is currently under medical care for a condition or disease.  A "subject" is someone who:  may have a condition that requires treatment, but is not under the care of a physician/is used for experimental purposes that have nothing to do with medical research/submits to medical research - not because of a health problem, but solely to supplement their income.

Comment: A 'subject' doesn't have to be doing it to supplement their income, there could be many reasons. But you are right that 'subject' doesn't imply that the person is ill.

Comment: In the medical establishment, there is a strong tendency for healthcare providers to simply make the connection "<person being given drugs/having procedures performed on them> = <patient>"; an understandable error, though erroneous nonetheless.

Comment: The authors are just pointing out that 'patient' and 'subject' are often the same (many subjects in experiments led by a physician are their own patients) but in some important instances they are distinct.

Comment: My Clinical Trials Unit uses the word 'participant' in all cases.

Comment: What is quoted in the question is an **abstract** of a paper; it is not meant to be a full exposition of the authors' argument. The only sensible way to find out what the argument is, is to read the actual paper. The question is effectively asking people to **guess** what the paper says on the basis of its abstract.

Comment: @jsw29 The question is "What is the difference between patients and subjects, in clinical research?". No guess to be made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is [a useful site of clinical terminology](https://www.fda.gov/media/108378/download).

A 'patient' is a person receiving medical care, while a 'subject' (or 'participant') is a person being experimented on. Often the two categories overlap, but not necessarily. For example a trial to ensure that a drug has no side-effects may involve giving it to people who are not sick, in which case they are a subject but not a patient. Also if a person is in the control group of a drug trial they are not receiving the drug, and it might be stretching the point to classify them as 'patients'.

Comment: New medications are not tested by giving them to people who do not have the condition the medication is intended to treat and who could therefore not benefit. That would be unethical.

Answer (score 0):

See

https://irb.uams.edu/2016/05/19/the-difference-between-a-patient-and-a-subject/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://irb.uams.edu/2016/05/19/the-difference-between-a-patient-and-a-subject/))

for an IRB's perspective.

Comment: Link-only answers are generally viewed as low-quality and are vulnerable to link rot. Please add the key points from the linked article to improve your answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/425143)